# How can I update MySQL with PHP, using the following syntax:

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
//connect to server

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","name","password");

//connect to db

mysql_select_db("complexm_pondlife", $connect);


//query the db

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM frogs");

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


?>

<button onclick="show()">SHOW DATA</button>

<p id="clip"style="visibility: hidden">



<?php
WHILE($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

$name = $rows['name'];
$age = $rows['age'];
$sound = $rows['sound'];
$id = $rows['id'];


?>
<?php
echo $id.") "."Name: ";
?>
<form action = "" method = "post">

    <input type="text" id="name" value='<?=$name?>'>

    <input type="submit" name="update_db" value="Update">

</form>
<?php
echo "Age: "."$age<br><br>";
echo "Sound: "."$sound<br><br>";
echo "___________<br><br>";


endwhile;

?>


</p>

<?php

function upload(){

mysql_query("UPDATE frogs SET name = '$name' WHERE name = '$name'");

}

if(isset($_POST['update_db'])){

    echo upload();

}

?>

<script>
function show(){
  document.getElementById('clip').style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>
```

This code gives me: Notice: Undefined variable: name in /home1/complexm/public_html/projects.php on line 70

I dont know why though. So if anyone can tell me i would like to know. If the syntax is wrong please tell me!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html <= start there.

Comment: @CarlosCarlsen - ***why*** doesn't it work for you?  What exactly doesn't work?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @dev I wanted it to upload MySQL database.

Comment: You're using a JS-based function syntax and trying to call a PHP-based function, that's one reason why it's not firing up.

Comment: Plus this `UPLOAD frogs
SET name = "$name"
WHERE name="TreeFrog";` you're missing quite a few things in there. Do Google "mysql update". Chances are, you'll end up back on Stack with q's and a's.

Comment: It is helpful when you give us all the parts. We have no idea what API you're using to connect with. You're probably mixing MySQL APIs, hard hard hard to say. Here, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. You will see all sorts of syntax errors.

Comment: `function upload(){ 

mysql_query("UPDATE frogs SET name = '$name' WHERE name = 'TreeFrog'");

}` there, valid. Please read up on doing queries and properly.

Comment: You're well on your way to success now. A word of advice though: Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is based on your [**original post**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26851691/2) and not marking it as an edit, should anyone wonder.

---

The reason why your `upload()` function is failing, is because you haven't included the [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function, along with a few missing parts. (Parts, being quotes/brackets).

```
function upload(){ 

mysql_query("UPDATE frogs SET name = '$name' WHERE name = 'TreeFrog'");

}
```

**A word of advice though:**

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

---

**Edit**:

To fire up your function using a PHP method, I recommend you change the
`<input type="submit" onclick="update()">` to
`<input type="submit" name="update_db" value="Update">` and wrapping an `isset()` around it.

I.e.:

```
<?php

function upload(){ 

mysql_query("UPDATE frogs SET name = '$name' WHERE name = 'TreeFrog'");

}

if(isset($_POST['update_db'])){

    echo upload();

}

?>
```

However, you will need `<form></form>` tags around your form's element(s) and a post method.

```
<form action = "" method = "post">

    <input type="text" id="name" value='<?=$name?>'>

    <input type="submit" name="update_db" value="Update">

</form>
```

---

**Edit #2**:

This is a `mysqli_` method, please change the DB credentials to match yours if they do not match.
I had to remove the `upload()` function, it was giving me too much trouble.

A hidden input has been added in the form, which is essential to doing updates like these.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//connect to server
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'name';
$DB_PASS = 'password';
$DB_NAME = 'complexm_pondlife';

$link = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($link->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
}

//query the db
$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM frogs");
?>

<button onclick="show()">SHOW DATA</button>

<p id="clip"style="visibility: hidden">

<?php
WHILE($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):

 $name = $rows['name'];
 $age = $rows['age'];
 $sound = $rows['sound'];
 $id = $rows['id'];

?>
<?php
 echo $id.") "."Name: ";
?>

<form action = "" method = "post">

    <input type="text" id="name" name="thename" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="the_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="update_db" value="Update">

<br>

</form>
<?php
 echo "Age: "."$age<br><br>";
 echo "Sound: "."$sound<br><br>";
 echo "___________<br><br>";

endwhile;

?>

</p>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['update_db'])){

$theid = stripslashes($_POST['the_id']);
$theid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['the_id']);

$thename = stripslashes($_POST['thename']);
$thename = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['thename']);

$results=  mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE frogs SET name = '$thename' WHERE id = '$theid'");
}

?>

<script>
function show(){
  document.getElementById('clip').style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>
```

You can also redirect to the same page by adding this at the top:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
?>
```

then adding this after your query:

```
if($results){
  header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/update_frogs.php");
}
```